# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges on oracle12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SESSION", line 122
ORA-06512: at "C##USER1.CP_UTILS", line 17
```

this is the package that generates the above error

```
13:   procedure setTaskId(PARAM_taskId number)
14:   is
15:     LOC_context varchar(30) := CONST_TASK_CTX||SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA');
16:   begin
17:     dbms_session.set_context( LOC_context, 'TaskId', PARAM_taskId );
18:     dbms_session.set_context( LOC_context, 'ModelId', null );
19:     dbms_session.set_context( LOC_context, 'SqlTrace', null );
20:   end;
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you try `grant execute on sys.dbms_session to <executing user>` as sysdba?

Comment: Thank you for reply.Yes I did.But it has the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context is bound to a stored program unit for security reasons.

So when you created the context via CREATE CONTEXT (you **did** create the context?) then you specify what stored program unit is allowed to set the value.

```
SQL> create context blah using p1;

Context created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p1 is
  3  begin
  4    dbms_session.set_context('BLAH','MYKEY','myvalue');
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure p2 is
  3  begin
  4    dbms_session.set_context('BLAH','MYKEY','myvalue');
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec p1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p2
BEGIN p2; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SESSION", line 130
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.P2", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 1
```